# esModuleInterop ignored by compiler

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a sapphire framework application and I'm using `lowdb` for the database. This is my typescript configuration:

```json
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,
        "incremental": true,
        "lib": ["esnext"],
        "module": "Node16",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "newLine": "lf",
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "ES2020",
        "useDefineForClassFields": true
    }
}
```

But, `lowdb` is a ES Module and my app is compiling in commonjs. As you can see, I enabled both `esModuleInterop` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`. But the error is still the same:

```
Error when loading '...\dist\commands\balance\slash.command.js': Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module ...\lowdb\lib\index.js from ...\dist\lib\database.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in ...\dist\lib\database.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

In the [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop), a file with `esModuleInterop` enabled should be like this:

```js
"use strict";
var __createBinding = (this && this.__createBinding) || (Object.create ? (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(m, k);
    if (!desc || ("get" in desc ? !m.__esModule : desc.writable || desc.configurable)) {
      desc = { enumerable: true, get: function() { return m[k]; } };
    }
    Object.defineProperty(o, k2, desc);
}) : (function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    o[k2] = m[k];
}));
var __setModuleDefault = (this && this.__setModuleDefault) || (Object.create ? (function(o, v) {
    Object.defineProperty(o, "default", { enumerable: true, value: v });
}) : function(o, v) {
    o["default"] = v;
});
var __importStar = (this && this.__importStar) || function (mod) {
    if (mod && mod.__esModule) return mod;
    var result = {};
    if (mod != null) for (var k in mod) if (k !== "default" && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(mod, k)) __createBinding(result, mod, k);
    __setModuleDefault(result, mod);
    return result;
};
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const fs = __importStar(require("fs"));
const lodash_1 = __importDefault(require("lodash"));
fs.readFileSync("file.txt", "utf8");
lodash_1.default.chunk(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
```

But my compiled `database.js` looks like this:

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const lowdb_1 = require("lowdb");
const node_1 = require("lowdb/node");
const path_1 = require("path");
const constants_1 = require("./constants");
const initialValue = {
    members: []
};
const adapter = new node_1.JSONFile((0, path_1.join)(constants_1.rootDir, 'database', 'db.json'));
const db = new lowdb_1.Low(adapter, initialValue);
exports.default = db;
```

So I think that typescript is ignoring `esModuleInterop`. How can I fix it?